# finding free regions using postgres range type

Tags: postgresql

I want to use range types in postgres to implement a reservation service. The basic schema is an `area` which represents a range, and a set of `reservations` that are subsets of the total area.

```
create table area (
  id int primary key,
  range int8range);

create table reserved (
  area int references area (id),
  range int8range);
```

I've been successful in doing some basic operations, but I'm stuck constructing queries that allocate unused space.

For instance, if an area with range [0, 100) has two reservations [20, 50) and [60, 90) and I'd like reserve a space of size 10 then I want to find a unused part of the total area (e.g. [0, 10)). However, if I want to reserve a space of size 30, then I would like to generate multiple non-contiguous regions (e.g. [0, 10), [50, 60), and [90, 100)).

Comment: What have you tryed? I think you need do a self join with reserved and then you will have the open slots very easy